# Using Bootstrap to position a span under a div

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, position, margin

I'm trying to implement more Bootstrap elements into a project I'm working on. I have a round div with some text beneath it "Go to Homepage". I'd like the span to be centered below the div and on one line-- how can I accomplish this with Bootstrap?

```css
.avatar {
 margin: 10px;
 border-radius: 50%;
 height: 90px;
 text-align: center;
 width: 90px;
 float: right;
 border: 5px solid #fafafa;
  background-color: blue;
}

.initials {
 font-size: 2rem;/* 50% of parent */
 position: relative;
 top: 1.2rem; /* 25% of parent */
 color: #fafafa;
 font-weight: 700;
 }
  
  .update-homepage-link {
 float: right;
 color: #fafafa;
 font-weight: bold;
  color: pink;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="col-6 col-xl-2 order-xl-3">
    <div class="avatar">
     <span class="initials"> WW </span>
    <a class="update-homepage-link" href="">Go to Homepage</a>
   </div>
```

Previously, I was using the following to get it to center below the round div, but I've been asked to complete the project in Bootstrap. I've been experimenting with spacing classes, but I haven't hit on the right combination. Can anyone give any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

It has nothing to do with bootstrap, please have a look at the modified CSS. If you want to center the contents, please wrap the complete div into another div with 'text-center' class.

```css
.avatar {
 margin: 10px;
 border-radius: 50%;
 height: 90px;
 text-align: center;
 width: 90px;
 border: 5px solid #fafafa;
  background-color: blue;
}

.initials {
 font-size: 2rem;/* 50% of parent */
 position: relative;
 top: 1.2rem; /* 25% of parent */
 color: #fafafa;
 font-weight: 700;
 }
  
  .update-homepage-link {
 color: #fafafa;
 font-weight: bold;
  color: pink;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="col-6 col-xl-2 order-xl-3">
    <div class="avatar">
     <span class="initials"> WW </span>
       </div>
                <a class="update-homepage-link" href="">Go to Homepage</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

I re-created your snippet, placing the solution under the old HTML.

I used a **Bootstrap Card component** to solve the problem and some other custom classes.

```css
.avatar {
  margin: 10px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  height: 90px;
  text-align: center;
  width: 90px;
  float: right;
  border: 5px solid #fafafa;
  background-color: blue;
}

.initials {
  font-size: 2rem;
  /* 50% of parent */
  position: relative;
  top: 1.2rem;
  /* 25% of parent */
  color: #fafafa;
  font-weight: 700;
}

.update-homepage-link {
  float: right;
  color: #fafafa;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: pink;
}


/* Classes for the solution */

.card.avatar-card {
  border: none;
  border-radius: 0;
}

.card-img-top.avatar-bs {
  width: 90px;
  height: 90px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 5px solid #fafafa;
  background-color: blue;
  justify-content: center;
  align-self: center;
}

.initials-bs {
  align-self: center;
  font-size: 2rem;
  color: #fafafa;
  font-weight: 700;
}

.update-homepage-link-bs {
  color: #fafafa;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: pink;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-6 col-xl-2 order-xl-3">
      <div class="avatar">
        <span class="initials">WW</span>
        <a class="update-homepage-link" href="">Go to Homepage</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- SOLUTION -->
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-6 col-xl-2 order-xl-3">
      <div class="card avatar-card" style="width: 18rem">
        <div class="card-img-top avatar-bs d-flex">
          <span class="initials-bs d-flex"> WW </span>
        </div>
        <div class="card-body text-center">
          <a class="card-title update-homepage-link-bs" href="">Go to Homepage</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```